# how to configure already running cluster in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a k8s cluster running ,having 2 slave nodes. Its been running few apps without any issue from some time. Now I need to add an app which required SCTP support. So I need to modify the cluster so that it support SCTP. I do not want to delete the entire cluster and recreate it. From google I understood that `--feature-gates=SCTPSupport=True` is required at the time of init.

Can someone tell me is there a way to do it on runtime ? or with minimum rework of cluster deletion/addition ?

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ helm install  --debug ./myapp
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '40409'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:40409"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] CHART PATH: /home/ubuntu/myapp

Error: release myapp-sctp failed: Service "myapp-sctp" is invalid: spec.ports[0].protocol: Unsupported value: "SCTP": supported values: "TCP", "UDP"
ubuntu@kmaster:~$
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you must pass this flag to kube-apiserver. How you can do that depends on how you set up the cluster. If you used kubeadm or kubespray then you should edit file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml and add this flag somewhere under "command" field (somewhere between other flags). After that kube-apiserver pod should be restarted automatically. If not - you can kill it by hand.